# JPA2: JOIN (Self Join) issue

Tags: java, mysql, multithreading, eclipselink, jpa-2.0

I am trying to fetch records from a table using Join (self join). I am using EclipseLink JPA2 and MySQL. Here is the native query that I using.

```
    select * from mytable as detail join (select max(timestamp) as maxtimestamp from mytable where id=" + theUser.getId() + " group by hnumber order by maxtimestamp limit " + <offset> + "," + <iTotalRecords> + ") as topconv on detail.timestamp=topconv.maxtimestamp order by detail.timestamp
```

I have following pojo class

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name="mytable")
    public class MyTable {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
        @Column(name="mytableid")
        private long lMyTableId;

        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="id")
        private User user; //this object has id, name and so on fields.

        @Column(name="timestamp", length=15, nullable=false)
        private String strTimestamp;

        @Column(name="hnumber", nullable=true)
        private String hNumber;

        //Getters and Setters.

    }
```

Here is method to fetch the records

```
    public List<MyTable> fetchRecords(User theUser, int iTotalRecords, long offset) throws Exception {
        if(null == theUser) {
            throw new Exception("Invalid input.");
        }

        EntityManager entityManager = getEntityManager();
        if(false == entityManager.getTransaction().isActive()) {
            entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
        }

        try {
            Query query = entityManager.createQuery("select detail from MyTable as detail join (select topconv, max(topconv.timestamp) as maxtimestamp from MyTable where topconv.User= :User group by topconv.hnumber order by topconv.maxtimestamp) as topconv on detail.timestamp=topconv.maxtimestamp order by detail.timestamp");
            query.setParameter("User", theUser.getUser());
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            List<SMS> resultList = query.getResultList();
            return resultList;
        } catch(Throwable th) {
            throw new Exception(th.getMessage());
        } finally {
            closeEntityManager();
        }
    }
```

To get and close EntityManager

```
    private EntityManagerFactory _entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("JPATest");
    protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        _entityManager = _entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
        return _entityManager;
    }

    protected void closeEntityManager() {
        try {
            if(null != _entityManager) {
                _entityManager.close();
            }
        } catch(Throwable th){}
    }
```

My application supports multi-threading. I getting the following error.

```
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An exception occurred while creating a query in EntityManager: 
    Exception Description: Syntax error parsing [select detail from MyTable as detail join (select topconv, max(topconv.timestamp) as maxtimestamp from MyTable where topconv.User= :User group by topconv.hnumber order by topconv.maxtimestamp) as topconv on detail.timestamp=topconv.maxtimestamp order by detail.timestamp]. 
    The join association path is not a valid expression.
    An identification variable must be defined for a JOIN expression.
    The query contains a malformed ending.
```

Looks like JOIN is not supported in JPA2 query, any other alternative please suggest. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Looks like you are mixing SQL JOIN syntax with JPA join syntax. JPA supports join but what you are trying is not usual self join. Your right table is not MyTable but a select with aggregated data. You probably need to write SQL join query  and then use createNativeQuery method of entity manager. For more information on JPA JOINs refer to http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17904_01/apirefs.1111/e13946/ejb3_langref.html

Comment: @Shailendra Can you please guide me an example to implement Self Join using CriteriaBuilder?